# Better way to repeat with alternative at the beginning

Tags: lilypond, repeats

Using LilyPond, I would like to repeat a section with an alternative at the beginning. My desired unfolded structure is "A-B-A-B-C-B", so that A becomes C the third time through. I have tried the following solution

```
music = \fixed c {
  \repeat volta 3 {
    \alternative {
       \volta 1,2 { s1_"A" }
       \volta 3 { s1_"C" }
    }
     s1_"B"
  }
}

\score { \music }
\score { \unfoldRepeats \music }
```

But I am looking for a solution where the folded version reads "A-B-C", with an alternative on "C" that leads back to a *fine* after "B", maybe via a segno.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The structure is easy: A-B repeated, then C then dal segno B until fine.

Comment: Thanks. That's how I pictured it but I can't find a way to translate this into a working lilypond script.

Answer (score 3):

The structure that you’ll want to use has both a *Volta* repeat loop (AB-AB) and a *Dal Segno al Fine* repeat loop (B-C-B), it will look something like this:

[image: Score: A; Sengo, B, Fine, repeat; C, D.S. al Fine]

#### Problem

In LilyPond both of these repeat structures work fine by themselves, but when they are combined like this it gets complicated.  This logical flowchart shows why:

[image: Flow chart: A to B, B1 to A, B2 to C, C to B, B3 to Fine.]

These loops aren’t sequential because the B is inside both.  But they aren’t nested either.  Also, they can’t be combined into a single loop because they are different types, and there is no way of indicating to LilyPond whether the `\volta n` instructions are referring to the volta loop or the segno loop.

(The `\repeat segno` structure has only been available since v2.23, so it’s relatively new and still needs some work — perhaps the developers need to create a `\segno n` command.)

#### Solution

To get around this problem, you can use some of the special repeat commands.  The command `\volta #'()` can be used to add markup/symbols (such as the manual segno repeat mark `\segnoMark`) to the folded representation of the score only.  The command `\unfolded` does the opposite.

But even with these, unfortunately, you’ll still end up having to write the B section out twice in the code (unless you make it a variable).

##### Code

The following will look right (like the image at the top of this answer) when folded, and importantly it will also unfold correctly.

```
    {
        \repeat segno 2 {
            \volta 1 {
                \repeat volta 2 {
                    s1_"A" |
                    \volta #'() { \segnoMark 1 }
                    s1_"B" |
                    \volta #'() { \fine }
                    \section
                }
            }
            \volta 2 {
                s1_"C" |
                \section
                \unfolded { s1_"B" | \fine }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed, I forgot to explicitly state the constraint (or my desire) of writing each part only once, but embedding the code in a variable kind of solves this issue. I also noticed that with the `\repeat segno` solution, there is an another implicit *segno* mark that would show if some music preceded A section. So, for this fairly common structure, it seems quite complex to fulfill all conditions (write music once, correct folded and unfolded structure).

Comment: @matvila I didn’t notice that extra segno mark before.  If you want to get rid of it, place `\omit\segnoMark 1` before the A section (inside or outside of the repeat structure).

Comment: This is all just a workaround for the problem that the two loops are inherently inseparable and both are competing for the `\volta n` command.  As I suggested, I think the developers probably need to make a separate `\segno n` command for a elegant solution.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help